# Alter breadcrumbs

Tags: breadcrumbs

I am looking around a way to alter my breadcrumb for a particular page,I am using tb_sirate theme and menu_breadcrumbs module.
I have tried altering the breadcrumbs using mytheme_breadcrumbs(), its working but I am not able to return it in way that it can match to breadcrumbs theme on the site.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is code I put on my theme template file and it worked

```
function tb_sirate_breadcrumb($variables) {
  $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];
  if ($breadcrumb[1] == 'Calendar') {
    $links[0] = l(t('Home'), '<front>');
    $links[1] = ('Events');
    drupal_set_breadcrumb($links);
  }
  $breadcrumb = drupal_get_breadcrumb();
  if (!empty(
      $breadcrumb)) {
    $crumbs = '<ol class="crumbs">';

    foreach (
    $breadcrumb as $value) {
      $crumbs .= '<li class="crumb">' . $value . '</li>';
    }
    $crumbs .= '</ol>';
  }
  return $crumbs;
}
```